# Can not change chapter number to tartibi in table of content

Tags: bidi, xepersian

I have a simple LaTex file like the one below:

```
   \documentclass{book}
    \usepackage{xepersian}
    \settextfont{B Zar}       
    
    \makeatletter
    \bidi@patchcmd{\Hy@org@chapter}{%
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
        {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
    }{%
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
        {\protect\numberline{\chaptername~\tartibi{chapter}}#1}%
    }{}{}
    \makeatother
    
    \begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{سلم}
    \section{یبسیبسیب}
    \chapter{بثیبسیب}
    \section{یبسیبسیب}
    \end{document}
```

But chapters in the table of content are still with numbers.

I also changed to file to the one below, but nothing changed.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{B Zar}

\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \if@mainmatter
    \refstepcounter{chapter}%
    \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
        {\protect\numberline{\chaptername~\tartibi{chapter}}#1}%
    \else
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
    \fi
    \else
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
    \fi
    \chaptermark{#1}%
    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
    \if@twocolumn
    \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
    \else
    \@makechapterhead{#2}%
    \@afterheading
    \fi}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{سلم}
\section{یبسیبسیب}
\chapter{بثیبسیب}
\section{یبسیبسیب}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\Hy@org@chapter` is an hyperref macro. Where does the first code you posted come from?

Comment: Your second attempt is lacking `\makeatletter/\makeatother` hence the failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\Hy@org@chapter` is an hyperref macro.  But even loading `hyperref` the patch attempt fails because original definition does not look like the one your provide (you could have used last argument to activate the "fail" branch to signal the problem).

As per the second approach it seems to work, but you need `\makeatletter/\makeatother`.